# Step by step help associating ad account with the app for app install events.

Tags: android, facebook

I am an advertiser. I want to set up an ad to track app installs on Facebook. I've created and registered the app with Facebook Developer. Now I am not sure how do I proceed further with associating app with the ad account. 
My developer has pure experience with app development and neither he doesn't know how to proceed further.